# Why lodash get returns undefined for nested object in the react production build?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, get, lodash

Actually, I know my question is s weird but really confused me. lodash functions are awesome and using them is a safe way to have a secure and clean code but in my react project when I use `get` function of lodash, in the **development environment** it works well as every developer expected.

```
import get from 'lodash/get';

const hostname = get(window, 'location.hostname');
// => returns the current hostname
```

But after I run `yarn build && yarn start` to make a production build of my ReactJS app and run it, its behavior is changed and returns `undefined`.

```
import get from 'lodash/get';

const hostname = get(window, 'location.hostname');
// => returns undefined
```

So in the production build, I try the `get(window, 'location')` and it returns the `location` object. but when I put a key of location the lodash `get` function returns `undefined`.

*Actually, in the production and just for nested it returns undefined*

Due to this issue, I just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832013), but no one answer it.

Comment: mmh. I made a minimal setup and in production mode I get 127.0.0.1 ... So I think you have to provide more of your code than this snippet.

Comment: Dear @madflow, My code is just it. but I guess there are some babel or webpack plugins that change some part of codes in the production build. I used [React Cool Starter](https://github.com/wellyshen/react-cool-starter) to start my project, but I use some plugins that maybe they ruin `lodash` `get` function in the production build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58251831#comments-58251831) I became passionate about testing my production build. So I listed all thing That happens on the production build of my project that maybe causes this issue.

At first, I doubted to babel plugins that I used for transpile, but none of them affect just on production, they affect for whole environments.

And at last, I find [LodashModuleReplacementPlugin](https://github.com/lodash/lodash-webpack-plugin). this plugin causes this issue.

Based on its doc:

> Deep property path support for methods like _.get, _.has, & _.set.

This plugin omit the deep path support on lodash get. **That's the point**.

Comment: Thanks, dear @madflow, I found why the issue happens.